# PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK vs IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION vs Whitelisting and which to use for a foreground service vs background service

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock, android-powermanager

Ever since doze mode got introduced in Marshmallow, and the further restrictions introduced with Oreo, doing continuous work in the background got harder. I read lots of articles that advise using either PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION to be able to do monitoring work in the background.

As far as I understand, starting Marshmallow neither can keep a background service override doze, as it will pause execution during doze. Starting Oreo, background services will totally stop if the app is closed. However, they can be useful when using a Foreground service to keep it running all the time even when the user turns off the screen. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Can someone clearly explain the difference between each method and when to use each?